# How to display off a div/class/id while scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, html, scroll

In the last post I've solved about fadein fadeout function( I needed to fade out an element with scrolling)Now I need to get the element to a display=none - display=block condiction while scrolling up/down because the transparent element(that is screen pinned) doesn't allow me to click some link on the page. Another solution for me could be to bring the object in a back layer but I don't know if is possible with a pinned element. I've used this for fade out, fade in.  :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">


    $(window).scroll(function() {
    if (getScrollTop() < 20) {
    $('#cc-m-12786466225').fadeTo(10,1);
    } 
    else { $('#cc-m-12786466225').fadeTo(10,0); } } );

    function getScrollTop(){
    if(typeof pageYOffset!= 'undefined'){
    //most browsers except IE before #9
    return pageYOffset;
    }
    else
    {
    var B= document.body; //IE 'quirks'
    var D= document.documentElement; //IE with doctype
    D= (D.clientHeight)? D: B;
    return D.scrollTop;
    }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I spot jQuery, and some strange function that does exactly what `jQuery.scrollTop()` does ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you look into the [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) and [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) jQuery methods since they do exactly that and work in a rather simple way. You could replace your fadeTo calls for fadeIn and fadeOut calls like this:

```
if (getScrollTop() < 20) {
$('#cc-m-12786466225').fadeIn(500);
} 
else { $('#cc-m-12786466225').fadeOut(500); }
```

Comment: I think using fadein/ fadeout doesn't change the final result, I don't want to make it invisible, I want to toggle out of the page like a display="none" command.

Comment: @vlk it does, **fadeIn** brings an element from display: none to display: block CSS properties with a smooth effect, and **fadeOut** does the opposite. Refert to the linked documentation for more info! :)